# Shapley Shubik power index from large samples in R

Tags: r, permutation

```
library(Deducer)
n.players <- 17
weight <- c(84,92,22,12,12,15,11,22,16,1,12,15,26,20,9,29,4)
quota <- sum(weight)/2+1
p <-n.players
n.cases <-factorial(p)
tab <- perm(1:p)
critical <- rep(0,n.cases)
for (i in 1:n.cases){
weight.sum <- cumsum(weight[tab[i,]])
critical[i] <- tab[i,which.max(weight.sum >= quota)]
}
table(critical)
power <- table(critical)/n.cases
round(power,3)
```

- this code needs "Deducer" package. Please type the message "install.packages("Deducer")" before you input the code.

If you need more information about Shapley Shubik power index, please visit here "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley%E2%80%93Shubik_power_index"

In this case, I get an error message because the code is based on large samples. I want to solve the problem in two ways as follows :

1. calculate a kind of cases as many as my personal computer allows (I bought my PC 5 years ago. It is not high performing in those days)and I check the processing time (It is easy. I just use the procedure "proc.time")
2. By using MonteCarlo, I want to approximate the index, and I also check the processing time in this case.

Furthermore, I would want to compare the indices and processing times from between the way1 and way2.

How can I solve this? (I cannot find the package which enlarge the limitation of memory for calculating. Even if I know the elementary level of montecarlo theoritically, I can not apply the mechanism to R code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` to generate random permutations, instead of enumerating all 17! of them.

```
n.cases <- 1e6
critical <- rep(0,n.cases)
for (i in 1:n.cases){
  random_permutation <- sample( 1:n.players )
  weight.sum <- cumsum( weight[ random_permutation ] )
  critical[i] <- random_permutation[ which.max(weight.sum >= quota) ]
}
table(critical)
power <- table(critical) / n.cases
round(power, 3)
```

Comment: When I need a real value of shapley shubik index, how can I enlarge memory for calculation in R? in this case I had better use "apply" instead of "for loop".

Comment: visit "http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/SocialScience/ShapleyShubikIndex.shtml". In this site calculate real value of index for a second. Even though I used "Monte Carlo" for the index, I spent more time than using the former site. I am very sorry to disturbing you

Comment: How can I transform your code by using "apply" for more fast calculation?

Comment: `Rprof` reveals that most of the time is spent in the `sample` function:
removing the loop would not make the code significantly faster.
Instead, you can try to reduce the number of samples, say
from 1,000,000 to 100,000 (but the third digit will not always be correct).

Comment: Thank you a lot. From what you say, for faster calculation, I had better find the packages which allow R to use more memory than depend on "Montecarlo" right? In this case, taking all cases is much more faster than "sampling" because random number generating time is relatively taking a long time.

Comment: Or JAVA has a faster calculation speed than R, inherently? (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/SocialScience/ShapleyShubikIndex.shtml%22 )

Comment: Is there any other solutions, for faster calculation, which do not take the degree of accuracy off? I am very sorry to disturbing you.

Comment: Considering all the cases, one by one, is not a good idea: 
there are really too many of them, it would take minutes or hours, whatever the language.
It may be possible to consider all the cases (i.e., have an exact result),
but not one by one: indeed, we do not have to list all of them, just count them -- 
but if so, it is not straightforward to implement.
A Monte Carlo approach with 100,000 samples seems reasonable to me.
If you want to increase the precision, but not the time, 
you can try to reimplement the algorithm in a compiled language, such as Java or C++.

Comment: You have been a lot of help. I just got a solution for faster speed ( http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/GeneratingFunctions.shtml ). I think that reading this material is valuable for you, too.